# How do tokens with royalties work?

Tags: spl-token, metadata, mpl-token-metadata

Im just trying to get some info regarding tokens with royalties, not nfts, fungible tokens. If Im not mistaken they follow the same metadata structure standard and many tokens have 0 royalties by default, I wanna know if that can be changed and how that would affect AMM, CLOB, etc